# Problems in Type Level Programming Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to do this in scala

```
abstract class Rel[A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode] {
  val from: A
  val to: B
}
abstract class NeoRel[C <: Rel[A, B] : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode]{
def save(c: C)
}
class NeoRelOperations[C <: Rel[A, B] : ({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode](c: C) {
  val neoRel = implicitly[NeoRel[C, B, A]]
def save() = neoRel.save(c)
}
object NeoRelOperations {
  def apply[C <: Rel[A, B] : ({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode](c: C) = new NeoRelOperations(c)
}
```

But I got problem with the implicitly:

```
val neoRel = implicitly[NeoRel[C, B, A]]
```

I get this on the compiler

```
Error:(88, 26) could not find implicit value for parameter e: com.kreattiewe.neo4s.orm.NeoRel[C,B,A]
val neoRel = implicitly[NeoRel[C, B, A]]
                     ^
Error:(88, 26) not enough arguments for method implicitly: (implicit e: com.kreattiewe.neo4s.orm.NeoRel[C,B,A])com.kreattiewe.neo4s.orm.NeoRel[C,B,A].
Unspecified value parameter e.
  val neoRel = implicitly[NeoRel[C, B, A]]
                         ^
Error:(99, 119) inferred type arguments [C,Nothing,Nothing] do not conform to class NeoRelOperations's type parameter bounds [C <: com.kreattiewe.neo4s.orm.Rel[A,B],A,B]
  def apply[C <: Rel[A, B] : ({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode](c: C) = new NeoRelOperations(c)
                                                                                                                      ^
Error:(99, 140) type mismatch;
 found   : C(in method apply)
 required: C(in class NeoRelOperations)
  def apply[C <: Rel[A, B] : ({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode](c: C) = new NeoRelOperations(c)
                                                                                                                                           ^
Error:(99, 119) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type com.kreattiewe.neo4s.orm.NeoRel[C,A,B]
  def apply[C <: Rel[A, B] : ({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L : Mapper, A: NeoNode, B: NeoNode](c: C) = new NeoRelOperations(c)
```

May be there could be another solution for the context bound handling

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example?

Comment: @TravisBrown Btw, the same err appears even with empty traits (I tried): `trait Mapper[T]` and `trait NeoNode[T]`

Comment: @DaunnC Ah, thanks—I'm super lazy and didn't try that out. I'll take a look later.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `implicitly[X]` you should either have `implicit val x: X = ...` or `implicit def makeX(...): X = ...` in scope.

Do you have some implicit val/def of type `NeoRel[C, B, A]` in scope?

Comment: yep, he tried to pass the evidence: `({type L[x <: Rel[A, B]] = NeoRel[x, A, B]})#L`

Comment: There's also `implicit class`, but AFAIK those need to not be abstract.